# Adding a default null value to a select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, haml

I currently have this line of code:

```
=select_tag :resource_id, options_for_select( Resource.find(:all, :conditions => "resourcetype = 'data-sheets' && category = 'Data Centres'", :order => "title ASC").map{|l| [l.title, l.id] }, @dc.try(:resource_id) )
```

Which works in the sense it displays a list pulled from the database, and selects the current value of the field, but I need to add a "please select" option to the top of the list with no value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option for "blank"

```
:include_blank => true
```

Additionally you can use `prompt` to set the value of that text